# Find a vaule from columns of a dataset asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dataset

I Want to find the value from dataset column Id.
here is the dataset

```
Id  Value
1   football
2   Tennis
3   Cricket
```

If any one is absent in Column then i want to append that particular value in the dataset

Comment: What does absent in column mean?

Comment: if id = 1 or 2 or 3 absent then i need to add thant particular row with dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is a DataTable inside a DataSet. First you need to query if the id is in the DataTable:

```
var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0]; //For this example I'm just getting the first DataTable of the DataSet, but it could be other.
var id = 1;
var value = "football";

//Any(...) will return true if any record matches the expression. In this case, the expression is if a Id Field of the row is equals to the provided id
var contained = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Any(x =>x.Field<int>("Id") == id);
```

Then, if it's not there, add a new row:

```
if(!contained)
{
    var row = dataTable.NewRow();

    row["Id"] = id;
    row["Value"] = value;

    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First you should use a loop to see if your dataset column 'id' contains the value. If the id is not existing then:

```
   DataRow newrow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); //assuming ds is your dataset
   newrow["id"] = "your new id value";
   newrow["value"] = "your new value";
   ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newrow);
```